# Error Converting Circular Structure to JSON...take 2

Tags: javascript, api, axios, circular-reference

How can I fix the error? I'm working in GoormIDE. I posted this question earlier, but had to take that post down. I've checked other posts, but I'm still a beginner and I'm following along a tutorial, so I would appreciate help on this specific problem. I see it has something to do with JSON.stringify...but I don't know what that is or where it would go...thanks for the help!

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const axios = require('axios');

app.listen(3000, function() { 
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); 
});

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=<myKey>&s=california")
    .then(function (response){
        res.send(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        console.log("There is an Error");
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'Socket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/workspace/webDevBootcamp2/APIs/API_Movie_App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/workspace/webDevBootcamp2/APIs/API_Movie_App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (/workspace/webDevBootcamp2/APIs/API_Movie_App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /workspace/webDevBootcamp2/APIs/API_Movie_App/app.js:12:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: `res.send(response.data)` - because the response data is in `.data`, and `response` itself will not be stringifiable as it will contain circular structure - but you only want the data anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object in axios is not just the response data from the request - as such it will contain "circular" references as it's a complex object

However, the response data will naturally be in a format that can be sent on

So, what you want to do is send the response data

```
.then(function (response){
    res.send(response.data);
})
```